# Remove padding and border around textField in UIAlertController

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, uitextfield, ios9

I'm attempting to implement a textfield inside a UIAlertController in Swift in iOS 9.3, somehow I'm getting padding and a top border around the textfield.

Please see the below screenshot, I've added a thick border around the textfield to highlight the padding and top border/line.

[image: Screenshot]

The code for my UIAlertController:

```
func handleLoginForgotPassword() {
    // create alert controller
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Password Reset", message: "\nEnter your email below and press Reset to reset your password.\n", preferredStyle: .Alert)

    // create text field for email
    alertController.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { textField -> Void in
        let tf = textField
        tf.placeholder = "Email Address"
        tf.autocorrectionType = .No
        tf.autocapitalizationType = .None
        tf.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()    

        tf.layer.borderWidth = 4.0
        tf.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(50).active = true

        // pull email from emailTextField if it exists
        tf.text = self.emailTextField.text
    }

    // create "OK" alert action
    let actionReset = UIAlertAction(title: "Reset", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) {
        UIAlertAction in
        NSLog("YES Pressed")

        // do something

        return
    }
    // create "Cancel" alert action
    let actionCancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel) {
        UIAlertAction in
        NSLog("NO Pressed")    

        // do something

        return
    }

    // add the actions
    alertController.addAction(actionReset)
    alertController.addAction(actionCancel)

    // present the controller
    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

This behaviour seems odd and I can't find it referenced when searching for a similar issue.

Comment: You have set the borderWith to 4.0 and that is the reason why you are seeing a border. Remove that line and the border will disappear.

Comment: @ChristianAbella That border is only there to illustrate the padding/border issue around it. Here it is without the border: [http://i.imgur.com/5gckZVu.png](http://i.imgur.com/5gckZVu.png)

Comment: which padding do you want to be removed? top , left?

Comment: @ChristianAbella the padding all around the textfield. I just want it to look like a normal textfield essentially. Why is there this white spacing around the edges of this textfield? And the line/border on the top of the area?

Comment: I tried your code but removed these two lines and the padding is gone:

tf.layer.borderWidth = 4.0
tf.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(50).active = true

Comment: This is what mine looks like with those removed: [http://i.imgur.com/4ltaVRX.png](http://i.imgur.com/4ltaVRX.png). If it's not happening to you then I will assume that some code somewhere else in my project is causing this. Thanks for your help @ChristianAbella

Comment: I added an answer, the constraintEqualToConstant function is only available from iOS 9.0. It could be the one causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The constraintEqualToConstant function is only available from iOS 9.0,  you need to add checking to your code if you want to support iOS version older than 9.0. This could be the one causing the issue.

```
if #available(iOS 9.0, *) 
{
  tf.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(50).active = true
} else 
{
  // Fallback on earlier versions
}
```

Comment: I'm deploying this to a iOS 9.3 device so I don't think this is the issue. Thanks for the suggestion.